# Deployment or Registration Fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, com, code-generation

I am creating a Smart Device Project Programmatically.

I generate the UUID for the Classes and Interfaces for the ATL Object Programmatically too.

It builds fine.

But when I Create the COM Server by CoCreateInstance method, it fails with the

following error: Error 0X80040154

What will be problem.  What am I missing while generating the Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the COM server is not registered. You have to register it with Regsv32.exe.